# Play2 create client websocket

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

How can I create client WebSocket in Play2 using Scala?

Should I use external library?
I found:
http://backchatio.github.io/hookup/

Do you know any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I believe play currently lacks client side web sockets but this may change in future as Akka-HTTP is integrated with play. However for now since you can call java from scala you can use javax.websocket or jboss.netty.

Answer (score -2):

A good example for Play 2 Scala Websocket (both client-side and server-side) can be found here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.2.2/samples/scala/websocket-chat

Comment: I saw this project, I want to create websocket client on server-side